# Spit a function to standalone js

Tags: typescript

I have a function `builddefs` that returns a function `handlerRequest`

`builddefs` is only useful during development and I need to deploy `handleRequest`.

Thus can ts give a seperate file containing only `handleRequest` and its dependencies

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAIxDANgE0wU2AZwAoBDALkXygCcYwBzAGhXLBAFtkcqBKcw7xAF4AfIgBucGJkQBvALAAoRMsRUcUEFSShIsBIn6zFKk4mBwqB9OopQcAByGIADAG5bDxAB4U7yg4BqAIF5JVNlCAR8OGsAOnQ4OhJuY3DEAF9U5UyFHMVIsEpEAAtiMExrKgAlHABHEBwiwRQ0LFwCQgAiZGtizqYAFhSFRVLyypr6xqh%20IA)

Comment: Not sure what you mean, because `handleRequest` is returned inside `builddefs`, I don't think it's possible to "split" it into a separate file

Comment: `handleRequest` is return object of `builddefs` , after it has been returned , I want the function to be stored so it doesn't need to be computed everytime for execution